# Can't create new post | Wordpress API | Backbone JS | Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

Tags: wordpress, backbone.js, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to user Wordpress' Backbone.js client to create a new post.

```
var post = wp.api.models.Post({ title: "Lorem ipsum", status: "publish" });
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    at Object.h.Model (backbone.min.js?ver=1.4.0:formatted:232)
    at Object.i (backbone.min.js?ver=1.4.0:formatted:1247)
    at Object.i (backbone.min.js?ver=1.4.0:formatted:1247)
    at Object.i (backbone.min.js?ver=1.4.0:formatted:1247)
    at Object.i (backbone.min.js?ver=1.4.0:formatted:1247)
    at Object.i (backbone.min.js?ver=1.4.0:formatted:1247)
    at Object.i (backbone.min.js?ver=1.4.0:formatted:1247)
    at Object.i (backbone.min.js?ver=1.4.0:formatted:1247)
    at Object.i (backbone.min.js?ver=1.4.0:formatted:1247)
    at Object.i [as Post] (backbone.min.js?ver=1.4.0:formatted:1247)
```

Has anyone had a similar problem? I can't find a solution anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1** - Enable `wp-api-fetch` as a dependency for your script :

```php
wp_enqueue_script('my-script', 'path/to/my/script.js', array('wp-api-fetch'));
```

**Step 2** - In the `path/to/my/script.js` call the rest-api to create a new post like this :

```js
wp.apiFetch({
  path: 'wp/v2/posts',
  method: 'POST',
  data: { title: 'New Title'}
}).then(post => console.log(post))
```

This **answer** brings up some other use cases :

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/361012/119120

More info in **REST API Handbook** about  the javaScript/Backbone client library :

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/backbone-javascript-client/